# how to change the field value of objects in array from string to array of string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "shop": "pepe",
    "fruits": [
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "taste": "sweet",
      },
    ]
}
```

Now i want to change the type of fruits.taste to an array like this: `"taste": ["sweet"]`

So the result should be this:

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "shop": "pepe",
    "fruits": [
      {
        "name": "banana",
        "taste": ["sweet"],
      },
    ]
}
```

i was trying to do that like this in a mongo playground query but that does not work:

```
db.getCollection('shops')
  .find()
  .forEach(function(document) {
   db.shops.update(
      { _id: document._id },
      { $set: { "document.fruits.$[].taste": [document.fruits.$.taste] } }
   );
})
```

How can i change in objects, which are in an array, a value from string to an array of string ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it by using a pipeline in the `update`.

```js
db.shops.update({
  "fruits.taste": {
    "$exists": true
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "fruits": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$fruits",
          "as": "fruit",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$fruit",
              {"taste": ["$$fruit.taste"]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HE6pt9NdkV4).

Comment: thank you so much, that works! how does that double dollar sign $$ work?

Comment: @LucienChardon You can think of `$$`, in this case, as accessing the user defined local variable `"fruit"` within the `"$map"`. See [Aggregation Variables](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) in the docs for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- you need to refer to an existing field, and use `$taste` so you need a pipeline update
- map on `fruts`, and put the `taste` value inside `[]`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6356f4fe424f6130d7f1214f)

```js
shops.update(
{},
[{"$set": 
   {"fruits": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$fruits",
        "in": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$this", {"taste": ["$$this.taste"]}]}}}}}],
{"multi": true})
```

Comment: thank you so much, this also works! unfortunately, i do not have enough experience points yet to vote your answer up as well :(

Comment: no worries, gl with your project : )